# Chromecast receiver application cannot play widevine drm protected content from Android sender application

Tags: android, chromecast, widevine, custom-receiver

I'm using receiver application from Expressplay's site for chromecast. **https://www.expressplay.com/developer/test-apps/#ccplayer**.

I've tested it from the browser by passing **license URL** along with the **widevine stream path**. It played the video, means that the receiver is working fine.

The problem appears when I try to play content from an android sender application. I'm passing the **license URL** in a **json** object.

My android sender code is as follows.

```
private MediaInfo buildMediaInfo() {
    MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Subtitle");
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Title");
    jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    try{
       jsonObj.put("licenseUrl","https://wv.test.expressplay.com/hms/wv/rights/?ExpressPlatToken=****");
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e(null,"Failed to add description to the json object", e);
    }
    return new MediaInfo.Builder("stream path.mpd")
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setContentType("video/mp4")
            .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
            .setCustomData(jsonObj)
            //.setStreamDuration(player.getDuration())
            .build();
}
```

I'm guessing that the problem maybe with recevier's code for the case of playing from android in setting the **licenseUrl**.

**My receiver code setting license URL is as following.**

```
if (event.data.customData && event.data.customData.licenseUrl) {
                    console.log('setting license URL');
                    host.licenseUrl = event.data.customData.licenseUrl;
                }
```

`event.data.customData.licenseUrl` license URL is not getting set in case of android.

- **Result while playing from android sender is Black screen.**
- **When playing from browser sender is plays the video.**
- **CORS** is enabled on the S3 server which is hosting the video contents.

Can Anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Does the JSON object passed from android not setting license URL ? If yes then how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your kind interest and worthy time to my problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that in my Receiver app `event.data.customData` was undefined while connecting from android sender application.

So I used `event.data.media.customData`

And accessed the key as follow:

```
if(event.data.media.customData['licenseUrl'] !== null){
                    console.log('setting license URL from mobile');
                    host.licenseUrl = event.data.media.customData.licenseUrl;
                }
```

That was it! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so, check [DRM support](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#drm) wherein it was stated that,

> To fully support content protected with Digital Rights Management (DRM), you need to implement a [Custom Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver). With a Custom Receiver, you can set up authentication and tailor your application according to your DRM requirements.

Note that, your receiver app accesses the Receiver API with the following reference:

```
//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js
```

Also, to develop a custom receiver application, you will need to [register](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration) your app with the [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/signup).

Then, for the Android Sender App, check the following:

- [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_setup#prerequisites)
- [ensure that the correct Google Play services APK](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk) is installed on a user's device since updates might not reach all users immediately.
- add the basic Cast features to your app, go to [Integrate Cast v3 into your Android App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate).

Comment: Thank you for a response to my problem sir. I've done everything they've told to do in documentations. I've been reading and implementing them for over more than a week. I guess everything is set e.g; dependencies, sdk etc.

Comment: the receiver I'm using is working fine when the request is from a browser sender. The problem occurs when I try to play from android sender.

Comment: Can you please provide me code that is setting customData of widevine content. Or any other way to set license url and token in android?